# Initialize struct when declaring or in separate function

Tags: c, performance, struct, initialization, arm

I am working with a bunch of structs in C as I begin my GUI library. I am having a difficult time deciding how to initialize the structs. Here are the two cases:

```
#define GUI_CreateBox(PageName,x,y,z,w,h,color) \
  struct GUI_BOX BoxName = {x,y,z,w,h,color}
```

or

```
static void GUI_InitBox(struct GUI_BOX *box,uint32_t x, ... uint32_t color)
{
  init code
}
```

My question is, which one would use the least code space? I figured the function would be better. I wanted to use the define because it would be much faster than dereferencing the struct pointer a bunch of times. I just do not understand how the initialization of structs works and wanted a second opinion before I proceed.

What does everyone think?

Also some background info. I will be working on ARM Cortex M-4 devices. I want a nice library.

Comment: The least space likely would take to use a simple initialiser and not to call that function at all, considering the overhead for passing all fields to the function which seems to do nothing else than store the parameters to the fields anyway. Otherwise, your question is too broad. This is no discussion forum.

Comment: Try both, see which works out best in practice (for whatever appropriate definition of 'best'); it depends on more factors than it's possible to reason about at this level.

Comment: Presumably, the `PageName` parameter and `BoxName` variable are meant to be one and the same (in the macro initializer).

Comment: Well I just tested it and it seems like the function requires less code. I don't know why but I still think I will use the define. Does that sound like a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

How many of these particular initializations will you be doing? How many variations on these initializations will you be doing?  That may affect what gives you the least code.  Which of these need to be applicable to variables at global (file) scope?  You can use the macro at file scope; you can't use the function at file scope — the function call must be made within the body of a function, which also leads to questions about "when is the variable initialized".

Note that the macro version means you write:

```
GUI_CreateBox(box1, 23, 45, 20, 30, 20, COLOUR_BLUE);
```

but the function version means you can write:

```
struct GUI_Box box2;
GUI_InitBox(&box2, 23, 45, 20, 30, 20, COLOUR_GREEN);
…some code using box2…
GUI_InitBox(&box2, 32, 54, 2, 3, 2, COLOUR_PURPLE);
…more code using box2…
```

That also leaves you an option of not initializing the structure; that may not be a good idea.

Your choice.  There isn't a lot to choose between them.

You might consider a compound literal too:

```
#define GUI_INITBOX(x, y, z, h, w, c) \
    (struct GUI_BOX){ .x = (x), .y = (y), .z = (z), .h = (h), .w = (w), .color = (c) }
```

Then you'd write:

```
struct GUI_BOX box1 = GUI_INITBOX(23, 45, 20, 30, 20, COLOUR_BLUE);
```

to declare and initialize, and you could write:

```
struct GUI_BOX box2;
…code…;
box2 = GUI_INITBOX(23, 45, 20, 30, 20, COLOUR_GREEN);
```

to assign (not initialize) `box2` later.  Compound literals (and designated initializers) are part of C99 and hence also C11.

Comment: I only need to initialize them once, but there could be up to hundreds of these objects. Most of the structures are the same with x, y, w, h, and pointers. I used the similarity to create void pointer functions to move things around. I am big on code size and I found it increased my code. I don't know if it will matter in the end because initialization happens at the beginning so maybe I can deal with the slower function to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the fact that you are not going to be initializing but once. As far as code size is concerned, since your initialization routine has ONLY assignments, the macro would be smaller. Also with the fact that you don't have to use a function call nor pass in a bunch or arguments, you save on your stack size and also your throughput.

But one main thing you would want to consider is how many people would be using your library. I've ran into this quite a few times when people use libraries which are comprised of a lot of macros. There is no protection (parameter type checking) for your arguments, which could obviously lead to bad object initialization.

For that point alone, I would always err on the side of safety and go with doing this inside a function, especially when you consider that

And while this doesn't apply to your example, if you plan on reusing a single parameter multiple times in a function like macro, you could get some unexpected side effects for people who prefer to do an operation in the argument.